# Insert Into Multiple Value MySQL & PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm completely new on PHP & MySQL. I manage to add 1 value from table "products" but failed to add another one.

There is two row within products table like below:

products:

- product_name
- product_price

My code:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO products (product_name, user_id) VALUES (?, ?)";
 $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
 $statement->bind_param('si', $_POST['product_name'], $_SESSION['user_id']);

 if ($statement->execute()) {
   redirect_to("/create.php?created=true");
 } else {
   echo "Error: " . $conn->error;
 }
```

What is the correct way to add another row which is product_price ?

Comment: please properly format your code

Comment: Thank you @Akintunde-Rotimi . I have edit the code.

Comment: Are you asking how to add another database field or column?  Database fields or columns are not rows.  Fields are like id, name, price, etc.  Rows contain your data.

Comment: Do you want to use this like an "add to cart" feature where the first click populates with quantity 1 and the second adds +1 to that?

Answer (score 1):

if "porducts" table has a variable as 'product_price' then you can just update with it's primary id. every table must have primary id for identification.

Comment: Nope. Read what they wrote and take your conclusions.

Comment: @SimãoGarcia have to been to w3fools lately?  It's pretty empty and they are simply linking to a web.archive page.

Comment: Please don't link to w3schools. We're still repairing the damage it's done to the programming community with its hazardously out-dated advice. The official documentation for the [`UPDATE` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) is vastly better.

Comment: @tadman you are right. sorry me too new user in stackoverflow. and i will edit comments.

Comment: Thanks! Just trying to keep people from falling into that trap.

Answer (score 0):

You only have to put the column and the value on the SQL statement

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO products(product_name,product_price,user_id) VALUES('productNameValue','productoPriceValue',user_id);
```

Tell me if this works for you